# How can I replace a character (zero)?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, fontspec

Is it possible to replace characters in pdflatex? I use the Minion Pro and Myriad Pro font and the zero looks like a small 'O'. I want to replace the zero by a zero with a dot or slash in the middle ([Inserting slashed zero in non-OpenType supporting LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133073/inserting-slashed-zero-in-non-opentype-supporting-latex)). Is it possible to replace the character globally (I just want to write 0 instead of something like \zero)?

Is it possible in pdflatex or should I switch to lualatex (I have no experience in Lualatex but I have heard it has better font handling)?

Comment: It is possible but if the existing package doesn't support this out of the box, it will be a lot of work for a relatively small gain. If XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is an option, that will be by far the more straightforward option. Failing that, I would look to see if any fonts are already set up suitably for pdflatex. I'd only consider ways of creating support for this as a last resort. (And it would be a *lot* more hassle than e.g. just typing \zero now and again. It would be easier to just write a script to replace all your 0s with \zeros when done writing!)

Comment: You observe that the zero character "looks like a small 'o'." Are you using "oldstyle" (aka text-style) numerals instead of "lining" (aka "uppercase") numerals? AFAICT, there are no slashed variants of the "0" character for oldstyle figures -- at least not for Minion Pro and Myriad Pro. If you want slashed zeros, you should be using lining-style numerals throughout, not just for "0".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If switching to LuaLaTeX is something you're considering doing anyway, then you'll find that using a "slashed zero" is very straightforward: it's a simple option provided by the command `\setmainfont` (and `\setsansfont`) of the [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=SlashedZero]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Numbers=SlashedZero]{Myriad Pro}
\begin{document}
Minion Pro: 1001 007

\sffamily 
Myriad Pro: 1001 007
\end{document}
```

This program can be run under XeLaTeX as well. Incidentally, do note that the slashed zeros in the example above are being produced in *text mode*. There is apparently no such thing as a unicode-compliant slashed zero in math mode.

*Aside*: The most recent version -- released within just the past few days -- of the `luaotfload` package (which is loaded by `fontspec`) contains at least one serious bug that makes it crash with a cryptic and fairly useless error message. If you have TeXLive2013 on your system -- sorry, I don't have MikTeX and thus don't know what MikTeX users should do -- and you've recently run the TeXLive Manager program to update your distribution's packages, you can revert to the previous version of `luaotfload` by executing the command

```
sudo tlmgr restore luaotfload 31286
```

at a command prompt. Hopefully, a bug fix for this important package will be pushed to the CTAN soon.

Comment: Thanks Mico, you made my day! Especially the hint to the bug saved me some time. Everything works perfectly with LuaTex. I only have to convert my files to UTF-8 and do some minor changed in the preamble.

Comment: Damn it! Too happy too soon. It only works for normal text. If I use $0$ in a formula, I get the "standard" zero. I have read that I have to include \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}, \usepackage{MnSymbol} to get the Minion Pro math symbols in LuaTex. I am not sure but I think this package has no support for "slashed zeros". Can I use the MnSymbol package but set the numbers using Minion Pro and Slashed Zero option?

Comment: @user4811 - I tried to indicate in the 2nd para of my answer that there seems to be no slashed-zero glyph in any Opentype *math font*. (I checked Latin Modern Math, Asana Math, XITS Math, and Cambria Math: definitely no slashed zeros. Minion Math has a symbol of which I'm not sure if it's supposed to be a slashed zero or the "empty set".) This suggests that it's probably not advisable to use such a glyph in math mode.

Comment: I have found a solution and add it to your solution.

Answer (score 4):

One option with `pdflatex` (and without Minion font, sorry I do not have this font installed)  for small chunks of simple text (without any LaTeX command) could be the package `xstring`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\zero{\rlap{0}/}
\begin{document}
\StrSubstitute{%

102030 is a big number

But 1020030004000 is bigger

}{0}{\zero}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

As Mico commented, `\rlap{0}/` is not a very beautiful slashed zero, but the tuning of the slash position is not easy inside a string substitution. An easy alternative could be `$\emptyset$` but unfortunately is clearly bigger than the normal `0`. But it is possible to select a character much more similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\font\zerofont = cmsy7 at 9.3pt
\newcommand\zero{{\zerofont \char 59}}
\begin{document}
\StrSubstitute{%

102030 is a big number

But 1020030004000 is bigger

}{0}{\zero}

Zeroes comparison:
$\emptyset${\zerofont \char 59}0$\rlap{0}/$
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Comment: The "slash" character, `/`, is really too tall for the purpose of creating a "slashed zero" character.

Comment: @Mico. I agreed. It was only to show the character substitution with some more that another character as `$\emptyset$`(that also look ugly in this MWE). I will update the answer.