# Digit zero with a dot inside also in text mode

Tags: equations, numbering, empheq

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{empheq}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
\nfss@text{%
\sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
\sbox2{0}%
\sbox4{0\/}%
\ooalign{%
  0\cr
  \hidewidth
  \kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
  \raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
    \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
      \mathversion{bold}%
    \fi
    $\cdot\m@th$%
  }%
  \hidewidth
  \cr
  \vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}{align}
0 + 1 = 1
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to add `\pmzerodot` in equation number?

Related to: [Inserting slashed zero in non-OpenType supporting LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133073/inserting-slashed-zero-in-non-opentype-supporting-latex/133093#133093)

Comment: There is always \tag*{1\panzero}\stepcounter{equation}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example defines `\dotarabic`, which similar to `\arabic` prints the arabic form of a counter with the zeros exchanged by `\pmzerodot`.
`\theequation` is redefined to use `\dotarabic` instead of `\arabic`
(or `\arabic` can be redefined, if the zero with dot should be used by all counter outputs).

Furthermore `\pmzerodot` is made robust, because `\the<counter>` are subject
to the `\label`/`\ref` system. Fragile commands will break during the definition of the internal `\@currentlabel`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{empheq}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
  \nfss@text{%
    \sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
    \sbox2{0}%
    \sbox4{0\/}%
    \ooalign{%
      0\cr
      \hidewidth
      \kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
      \raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
        \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
          \mathversion{bold}%
        \fi
        $\cdot\m@th$%
      }%
      \hidewidth
      \cr
      \vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\dotarabic}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@dotarabic\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@dotarabic}[1]{%
  \expandafter\dotarabic@scan\number #1\relax
}
\newcommand*{\dotarabic@scan}[1]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {%
    \ifnum#1=0 %
      \ifincsname
        0%
      \else
        \pmzerodot
      \fi
    \else
      #1%
    \fi
    \dotarabic@scan
  }%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\dotarabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
  \addtocounter{equation}{9}
  \begin{empheq}{align}
    \label{eq:test}
    \pmzerodot + 1 = 1
  \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Perfect working, [Closed] @Heiko Oberdiek

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek, When all codes compiled `Illegal parameter number in definition of \@currentlabel' What will I do?

Comment: @Özgür Instead of `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\pmzerodot}`, you can try `\protected\def\pmzerodot`. Then `\pmzerodot` is robust by an e-TeX command. If it does not help, provide a MWE, I do not know, what you are doing.