# How to change the zero in increasing numbers with dotted zero?

Tags: tables, formatting, enumerate, page-numbering, itemize

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
  \nfss@text{%
\sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
\sbox2{0}%
\sbox4{0\/}%
\ooalign{%
  0\cr
  \hidewidth
  \kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
  \raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
    \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
      \mathversion{bold}%
    \fi
    $\cdot\m@th$%
  }%
  \hidewidth
  \cr
  \vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Zero}
Normal 0
\section{Resistor}
\pmzerodot
\subsection{Dot Inside In Zero}
0 \pmzerodot
\begin{enumerate}
\item Zero
\end{enumerate}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabular}{l}
0 \pmzerodot \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But what I'm trying to do, I want to change from zero to `\pmzerodot`, itemize and enumerate number, table caption number, caption number, section number, page number...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Of course I think it is possible. But I don't know how to do it. I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: Does the dot inside `0` have to be red (as shown in your screenshots), or could it be the color of the surrounding material (as is implied by the code you posted)?

Comment: There won't be a red dot. `\pmzerodot` will be. I used it to indicate the red color in the pictures. Its will be black.

Comment: Check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240271/120578

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267052/4686

Comment: @koleygr,I understand.

Comment: @jfbu, I did it.