# How to write "zero with short slash" in TeX?

Tags: crop, opentype, phantom, slanted

There is a similar application in the shortcuts below. However, I want the **end parts of the slash** to be deleted. So how can we create the fourth zero? Like  `\pmzerocomputer` .

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerocomputer}{%
    \nfss@text{%
        \sbox0{0}%
        \sbox2{/}% <--Be small slash. End parts of the slash to be deleted
        \sbox4{%
            \raise\dimexpr((\ht0-\dp0)-(\ht2-\dp2))/2\relax\copy2 %
        }%
        \ooalign{%
            \hfill\copy4 \hfill\cr
            \hfill0\hfill\cr
        }%
        \vphantom{0\copy4 }% correct overall height and depth of the symbol
    }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amstext}% for resizing the symbol in math

\begin{document}
    
\pmzerocomputer 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Related1: [Inserting slashed zero in non-OpenType supporting LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133073/inserting-slashed-zero-in-non-opentype-supporting-latex)

Related2: [How to write "computer zero" (with slanted vertical line) in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302650/how-to-write-computer-zero-with-slanted-vertical-line-in-tex)

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, or do you have to use use pdfLaTeX to compile your document?

Comment: @Mico, I'm not willing to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. I'm using pdfLaTeX to compile my document.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to tweak the parameters for different fonts, but here's my idea: picture mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\pmzero}{}{\mathord{0\mathpalette\pmzero@\relax}}
\newcommand{\pmzero@}[2]{%
  \llap{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#10$}%
    \begin{picture}(\wd\z@,\ht\z@)
    \linethickness{0.1\wd\z@}
    \Line(0.25\wd\z@,0.1\wd\z@)(0.75\wd\z@,0.9\ht\z@)
    \end{picture}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$0\pmzero0$

$\scriptstyle0\pmzero0$

$\scriptscriptstyle0\pmzero0$

\end{document}
```

[image]