# Tiny / Short slashed in zero

Tags: symbols, characters

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\begin{document}
$0\!\!\!/$
\end{document}
```

Hi, I will use zero but its inside slash.

[image]

Is it possible?

**SOLVE:**

It is work for me.

Related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133093/33075

```
\newcommand*{\pmzeroslash}{%
\nfss@text{%
\sbox0{0}%
\sbox2{\bf\tiny{/}}% % <----- added the \bf\tiny{/}
\sbox4{%
  \raise\dimexpr((\ht0-\dp0)-(\ht2-\dp2))/2\relax\copy2 %
}%
\ooalign{%
  \hfill\copy4 \hfill\cr
  \hfill0\hfill\cr
}%
\vphantom{0\copy4 }% correct overall height and depth of the symbol
}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

But it is must be corrected by you.

Comment: Have you tried `\emptyset`?

Comment: @GuM `\emptyset`'s slash protrudes out of the symbol `0`.

Comment: I think you should reword your question so as to make it clear what you are asking for.  BTW, are you sure that your readers will understand the meaning of such non-standard symbol?

Comment: Please edit the my question. Because my English is bad.

Comment: `\emptyset` is a little greater than zero.

Comment: @GuM this question is very clear, we need the symbol `0` with a slash inside as in picture.

Comment: @skpblack , this is not a full answer, but it's the only way I know to include a picture.

Comment: The question is not at all clear. The comments explaining it are much clearer. Why not just say 'I need a slashed-zero like this:'? But it is also not clear if you need the slash to be red. Is that part of the symbol? If not, why is it red?

Comment: Please, see the solve in my question. In my opinion, it is not duplicate. Check please.